# How to link to external sites in xampp

Tags: html, hyperlink, xampp, external

i am using Xampp and when i am trying access any online website using this code

```
<a href="www.xyz.com">Click</a>
```

it shows this in the url field

```
localhost/www.xyz.com
```

how to link to www.xyz.com directly ...

i also tried to use

```
<base href="">
```

but it doesn't seen to work .

i also tried using javascript and php redirects , but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

Try typing `http://www.mysite.com`. If you don't use `http://`, it thinks you're referring to a local domain (under `localhost`)

Comment: If you do `<a href="http://www.xyz.com">Click</a>`, what does it link you to then?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`<a href="//xyz.com">Click</a>`

From what I know, Xampp treats all requests as local requests. It adds localhost url to every href or img-src and the final link generated is localhost+https://*. I faced the same issue while getting a link from an API and displaying the image. I removed 'https:' from the received link and it worked for me.